# Database Algorithmic Scaling

Tags: database, algorithm, oracle, scaling

I've recently been tasked with doing some "big data" stuff with an existing Oracle database. The relevant table has 300 million entries, and is ridiculously slow. Are there any good books out there that explain how various options in the DB construction effect the algorithmic scaling (O(n), etc) of various queries? And how different query operations themselves effect scalings?

I'd prefer to get an understanding of how the underlying algorithms work rather than just ad hoc suggestions.

Comment: The answer really depends on how much you know about databases. Can you give some info on your background? If you have very little DB background, you should know your data has to be indexed properly - is that something you are doing?

Comment: My background is strong in general programming, but little specifically towards databases. That's why i'd like to understand the algorithms they use, how indices work, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan Lewis' book on Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals may be what you're looking for.

For particular techniques regarding querying large data sets the Oracle Data Warehousing documentation would be a good start.